# Firebase authentication limit login by the same user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

is there a way in Firebase to limit the number of logins by the same user at the same time, says I want to put a limit of 3 devices at a time for one single account, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not supported by Firebase. The best you can do is keep track of the token `auth_time`. This is the time of sign-in. You would keep a queue of 3 entries for that. Each time you sign-in a user, send their ID token for verification, add the `auth_time` to the queue (if it is not there already) and dequeue the oldest `auth_time` in the queue if it exceeds it maximum size (3) . You would only allow access to data for ID tokens with auth_times within that queue.

Comment: I don't think that it solve the problem because the tokens expires after an hour, so if a client open his app after that he will renew his token and the comparison will fail.

Comment: Token refresh will only update the `iat` field. The `auth_time` is the time the user signed in. That will remain the same no matter how often the token refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

I came around similar situation and then I implemented **bojeil** approach for limiting simultaneous login using one user credentials.

I have maintained following array field and number field in user document.

```
{
    allowed_auth_times : [
    
    ],
    max_granted_login : 3
}
```

Add entry into this array on

1. user signup.
2. If another person logs into the system using same credentials (either on same or different device) if `size(allowed_auth_times) < max_granted_login`

If `size(allowed_auth_times) == max_granted_login`
then remove oldest auth time, (`allowed_auth_times[0]`) and then add entry of new auth time.

This way you will make sure that, at any given point of time, limited users will be able to use the system. I have implemented this using Angular + AngularFire2
I will be more than happy if anyone can provide suggesting for improving this. Thanks in advance.

**Authentication Component :**

```
trySignInWithEmailAndPassword() {
    
    // Actual Signin process starts here.
    this._firebaseAuthenticationService.signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.userCredentials.value)
      .then((user) => {
        this._firebaseAuthenticationService.OTCheckAndUpdateDBAuthTime().then((result) => {
          bootbox.hideAll();
          if (result === true) {
            this._router.navigate(['/home']);
          }
        }, (err) => {
          bootbox.hideAll();
          bootbox.alert("Error Occured. Please contact support team with screenshot. " + err);
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error("Login failed. Redirecting user to authentication page.");
        bootbox.alert("Some Error Occured While Authenticating " + this.userCredentials.get("email").value);
        this._router.navigate(['/authentication']);
      });
  }
```

**FirebaseAuthService**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { first, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseAuthenticationService implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  uid: string = "";
  constructor(private _angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private _router: Router) { }
    
  trySignOut() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this._angularFireAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
        resolve();
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      }
      );
    });
  }

  getCurrentUserUID(): string {
    if (this._angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser != undefined || this._angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser != null) {
      let uid = this._angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
      if (uid == undefined || uid == null) {
        return "";
      } else {
        return uid;
      }
    }
    return this._angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  }

  getCurrentUserUID2(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this._angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(first());
  }

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userCredentials: any) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this._angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userCredentials.email, userCredentials.password)
        .then((userData) => {
          userData.user.getIdTokenResult().then((a) => {
            console.log("Auth Time : " + a.authTime);
            resolve(userData.user);
          });
        });
    });
  }

  signInUserWithEmailAndPassword(userCredentials: any) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this._angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userCredentials.email, userCredentials.password)
        .then((userData) => {
          console.log(userData);
          // If email is not verified then send verification email every time.
          if (this._angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.emailVerified == false) {
            this.sendEmailVerification();
          }
          userData.user.getIdTokenResult().then((a) => {
            console.log("Auth Time : " + a.authTime);
            resolve(userData.user);
          });
        }, err => {
          console.error("Error Occured During Signin user with email and password in auth service.");
          console.error(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

  // This function checks entry in allowed_auth_times [] depending on max_logins : in user profile.
  OTCheckAndUpdateDBAuthTime() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this._angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe((userAuthState) => {
        if (userAuthState.uid != null || userAuthState.uid != undefined || userAuthState.uid != "") {
          const user_doc_id = userAuthState.uid;
          this.db.collection("users").doc(user_doc_id).snapshotChanges().subscribe((docData) => {
            let doc: any = docData.payload.data();
            let allowed_auth_times_arr: string[] = doc.allowed_auth_times;
            let max_granted_login: number = parseInt(doc.max_granted_login);
            this.getAuthTime().then((currentUserAuthTime) => {
              if (allowed_auth_times_arr && allowed_auth_times_arr.includes(currentUserAuthTime)) {
                resolve(true);
              } else {
                if (allowed_auth_times_arr) {
                  if (allowed_auth_times_arr.length == max_granted_login) {
                    allowed_auth_times_arr.splice(0, 1);      // Delete Oldest Entry
                  }
                  allowed_auth_times_arr.push(currentUserAuthTime);
                  this.updateDBAuthTimesArr(userAuthState.uid, allowed_auth_times_arr).then(() => {
                    resolve(true);
                  }, (error) => {
                    bootbox.alert("Error Occured While Updating Auth Times. Please take screenshot of this and contact June Support team. " + error);
                    reject(false);
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          });
        }else{
          console.error("Authentication Service > OTCheckAndUpdateDBAuthTime > userAuthState is blank");
        }
      });
    });
  }

// Update 

  updateDBAuthTimesArr(uid: string, allowed_auth_times_arr: string[]) {
    return this.db.collection(environment.collctn_users).doc(uid).update({
      allowed_auth_times: allowed_auth_times_arr
    });
  }

// Get Auth Time of Currently Signed in User

 getAuthTime() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this._angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((userAuthState) => {
          if (userAuthState) {
            userAuthState.getIdTokenResult().then((tokenResult) => {
              console.log("Token result obtained. ");
              console.log("Auth time obtained : " + tokenResult.authTime);
              resolve(tokenResult.authTime);
            });
          } else {
            console.error("Blank UserAuthState Captured.");
            reject(null);
          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error Occured while obtaining the auth time of the user.");
        reject(null);
      }
    });
  }

**// You will be using this in other components. If there is entry of authTime in allowed_auth_times array then keep this user signed in, otherwise signout forcefully.**
  validateAuthTime(uid: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable<any>((observer) => {
      this.db.collection(environment.collctn_vendor_list).doc(uid).snapshotChanges().subscribe((docData) => {
        let doc: any = docData.payload.data();
        this.getAuthTime().then((currentUserAuthTime) => {
          if (doc.allowed_auth_times.includes(currentUserAuthTime)) {
            observer.next(true);
          } else {
            console.log("ValidateAuthTime > else : Observer returning false.");
            observer.next(false);
            //this.trySignOut().then(() => {
              //this._router.navigate(['/authentication']);
            //});
          }
        });
      });

    });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Database (Realtime Database or Firestore) to save user’s devices and check from there if he can login.